# Parallel read of numpy *.npz files (ideally using async/await syntax) for improved performance

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I have a TensorFlow input pipeline that accepts `.npz` files which each contain an example.  In groups of 5, I am writing them to TFRecords.  This is slow. The slowness is `np.load()` of the `npz`s which is roughly 10 seconds for each ~50MB file.

Since I will have many `.npz`s, I'd like to process them in parallel.  I'm assuming that `np.load` is I/O bound.  Can I use async/await syntax to make the loading faster? (`tf.io.TFRecordWriter` seems to be fast enough to ignore).  Or would you suggest another approach?